# Making an entire div clickable using jQuery (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a wordpress installation and am trying to create a function that makes an entire div clickable based on the href within it. I've found a lot of documentation that tells me to do this.

```
jQuery(".myBox").click(function($) {
    window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    return false;
});
```

But it's not working, nothing happens upon clicking. What's odd though is that if I do this just as a test

```
jQuery(".myBox").click(function($) {
    window.location = "http://www.google.com"
    return false;
});
```

then it does work and the div will redirect to google.com, so it doesn't seem to be a problem with the way I'm implementing the script. Am I going wrong with the first method somewhere? Here's my HTML

```
<div class="myBox">
<p><a href="http://www.example.com/notworking">This whole box should link but doesn't.</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: You're issue is that you are passing `$` into the click event handler.  That first argument is the `Event`, not `jQuery`

Comment: Could I ask why you don't put the div inside the anchor tag? Isn't this an option? if it is, you'd save yourself the functions etc. Could I also ask whether you actually have a function named $ which is firing everytime you click on it? https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: @ItrysohardbutIcryharder There isn't a function named `$`.  The user is under the assumption that the first argument provided to the event handler it jQuery.  It is not.  They most likely got this confusion from the usage of `$(document).ready()` which **does** pass jQuery in as the first argument

Comment: @Taplar I already assumed such thing, but I would rather ask for clarification, instead of jumping to conclusions.

Comment: Given that they have `$` on the parameters, asking if they have a function named `$` is rather beside the fact.  Regardless of what functions they may have, `$` inside that function will be what is passed in.

Comment: @I try so hard but I cry harder it's because the pagebuilder I'm using has issues with anchors outside of divs and for some reason strips them out of the code when I use the visual editor. Also with that method it's not always possible to set the height to be inherited from the parent and make the whole area clickable

Comment: @Taplar correct. I should've explained myself better.

Comment: @Taplar this is where I say that I don't know s**t about jQuery. Are you saying to remove the `$` before `(this)`? Also FWIT I'm placing the code inside my theme's 'Custom JS' box, which contains this sentence

__"To use jQuery code wrap it into jQuery(function($){ ... });"__

Comment: You need to remove `$` from the arguments.  Rename `$(this)` to `jQuery(this)` and it will work.  Otherwise you can `var $ = jQuery` before all the logic and just use `$`, or use can use an IIFE or document ready to scope jQuery down to `$`

Comment: @Taplar bingo, that did it. Thank you I should've clocked that myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(".myBox").click(function($) {
    window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    return false;
});
```

Your issue is that you have `$` on the parameters of the click event handler.  That variable passed in is the `Event` generated, not `jQuery`.  There are a few ways to fix this.

## 1. Using the global variable

```
jQuery(".myBox").click(function() {
    window.location = jQuery(this).find("a").attr("href");
    return false;
});
```

## 2. Storing jQuery in $

```
var $ = jQuery;

$(".myBox").click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    return false;
});
```

## 3. Using a document ready that passes jQuery in, allowing you to name it $

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $(".myBox").click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    return false;
  });
});
```

## 4. Using a simple IIFE.  Similar to a document ready, but less overhead

```
(function($){
  $(".myBox").click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    return false;
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: That's it, I hadn't clocked having to change the event handler an additional time in the second line. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I̶n̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶H̶T̶M̶L̶,̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶d̶o̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶e̶l̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶c̶l̶a̶s̶s̶ ̶`̶m̶y̶B̶o̶x̶`̶.̶  (this was fixed in an edit)

A couple of points though, do you really need jQuery for this? It seems like using a hammer to kill a fly. Usually for "entirely clickable elements", you can use a `relative` positioned parent, `absolute` positioned link, and set it to the top/left and 100% width and height.

```css
.myBox{padding:10px;border:1px solid #ccc;position: relative;}
.cover{ position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
.cover:hover { background:rgba(0,95,235,.25);
```

```html
<p class="myBox">This whole box should link.<a href="#" class="cover"></a></p>
```

You also have the option of putting the anchor outside whatever you want to link (based on your edit, I see this may not be an option?):

```css
.myBox{padding:10px;border:1px solid #ccc;position: relative;}
```

```html
<a href="#"><p class="myBox">This whole box should link.</p>
```

If you DO need jQuery for some reason, you can handle all of your jQuery functions in a single `ready` function, and pass the click event handler to it. (Note, you should also handle the situation where a link is NOT present, otherwise you'll send users to a blank/broken URL if its clicked on):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.myBox').on('click', function(){
    var location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    if( location )
      window.location = location;
  });
});
```

```css
.myBox{ padding: 10px; border: 10px; }
.myBox:hover {cursor: pointer; background: #0095ee;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myBox">
  <p>This is test.<a href="https://example.com/">This is a link</a></p>
</div>

<div class="myBox">
  <p>This is with no link</p>
</div>
```